# How to lay out HTML divs relative to one another like Android's RelativeLayout?

Tags: html, css, layout

I'd like to lay out HTML divs relative to one another, like [Android's RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html#Example).

Any idea how to achieve it? Thanks.

**EDIT**: The question is a general one but I see people request a specific example so here's the one from the link. You can simplify the example layout requirement to be: Blue square from start to finish. Below it two squares: Red and Yellow. Yellow to the right of red till the end. Below the yellow, a green square aligned to the right. Overall 4 divs, laid out relative to one another.

[image] [image]

Comment: Can you illustrate what have you tried so far?

Comment: Can you provide an illustration of the layout you want to achieve?

Comment: Added the example from the link and wrote a simplified requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Like Android, in HTML you cannot directly define Linear or Relative Layout. But through CSS you can define whatever design you want.

For example, in your question you have asked four inputs to align in a particular format.

You can wrap all inputs in a div, and make it align using *float* property.

[The layout is here.](http://jsfiddle.net/eme4L4q0/)

Edit: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/eme4L4q0/1/) is the layout with .div2_2 in px value.

You can achieve this layout using the following html and css.

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="div1">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Reminder Name"/>
    </div>
    <div class="div2">
        <div class="div2_1">
            <input type="text" value="Wed, Jun 27, 2012"/>
        </div>
        <div class="div2_2">
            <input type="text" value="8.00am"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="div3">
        <div class="div3_1">
            <input type="button" value="Done"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div{
    padding: 3px 0;
}
input {
    width: 100%;
}
.parent{
    width: 400px;
}
.div1, .div2, .div3{
    width: 100%;
}
.div2{
    display: inline-block;
}
.div2_1, .div2_2{
    display: inline-block;
}
.div2_1{
    width: 55%;
    float: left;
}
.div2_2{
    width: 44%;
    float: right;
}
.div3_1{
    width: 30%;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
}
```

I hope this will be helpful for you.

Comment: If I change `div2_1` to an absolute width in pixels, everything collapses, because `div2_2` isn't defined to be to the right of `div2_1`. See the change to pixels here: http://plnkr.co/edit/I5Lk65ekR97KC2mclemn?p=preview.

Comment: If you change the width in px for .div2_2, then you have to add .div2{display: inline-block}

Answer (score 0):

You can put divs on the same 'line' by using the display property in CSS.

Use

```
display: inline;
```

or

```
display: inline-block;
```

'inline-block' means your div can be given height and width properties while 'inline' will just be the size of your content.  In this case, you'll probably want to use inline-block so you can line up your divs.

Answer (score 0):

Found a way using [float](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp) and [clear](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <div style="width: 100%; height: 50px; background-color: blue;"></div>
  <div style="width: 60%; height: 50px; background-color: red; float: left"></div>
  <div style="width: 40%; height: 50px; background-color: yellow; float: left"></div>
  <div style="width: 40%; height: 50px; background-color: green; clear:left; float: right">
</body>
</html>
```

You can play with the code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/inl1qgMM5QgAvJUtDkkN?p=preview).

* The purpose of `clear:left` is to keep the green in the next line - even when the sizes of the red and yellow get changed to pixels instead of percentage.

[image]

Comment: Try loosing the `float: left`. Surprise yourself.

Comment: Here's another version that positions the green right below the yellow: http://plnkr.co/edit/c0JrLSSkAvpyWyhgkfCU?p=preview

Comment: Anyhow, this, as every other solution here so far, sucks! Nothing is relative to another. Everything is constant!!!

Comment: This is crap because I assume all the elements fill the whole view. Sometimes, the blue element has a specific length and I want to align right the yellow and the green.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this page to find out how to layout your webpage in a "Grid System"

getbootstrap.com/css

Comment: While a link may be helpful, please try to include the important information in your answer.